# Case-When in Group By with Columns of Different Data Types

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic, types, group-by

I want to have a query which dynamically chooses the column to group by.

Suppose I have this table:

[image: Sample Table]

I want to see the results grouped by a variable:

```
Declare @grouBy varchar(50)
Set @grouBy = 'name' -- or 'job' or 'jobCode'
```

I wrote a query:

```
SELECT MIN(Name), MIN(job), MIN(jobCode), MAX(salary)
FROM TempTable
GROUP BY
    Name,
    CASE
        WHEN @grouBy = 'job' THEN job
        WHEN @grouBy = 'jobCode' THEN jobCode
    END
```

It errors saying:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'programmer' to data type int.

My question is how does the data type matter in this grouping?

I also tried to put the `CASE` in the `SELECT` statement but got the following error:

> Column '....' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Note that `Group by Name,` before the `Case` means you will always first-level group on `Name`.  Is this what you want, or do you mean to have just single-level grouping by the `CASE` expression - e.g. by adding `when @grouBy = 'name' then name` to it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to settle on a common data type for the columns that you are essentially merging in the `CASE`.

A `job` value like `'programmer'` cannot be converted to an `int` of course.

Explicitly cast `jobCode` to `job`'s string data type then.  For example, if `job`'s data type is `nvarchar(50)`, use something like this:

```
Declare @grouBy varchar(50)
Set @grouBy = 'job' -- or 'name' or 'jobCode'

Select 
    min(Name), min(job), min(jobCode), max(salary)
from TempTable
-- FORNOW: for quick testing/debugging
--from (
--    select 'whatever' as Name, 'a' as job, 1 as jobCode, 1000 as salary
--    union
--    select 'who cares', 'b', 2, 2000) t
Group by Name,
Case 
    when @grouBy = 'job' then job
    when @grouBy = 'jobCode' then cast(jobCode as nvarchar(50))
End

/* FORNOW: quick testing/debugging results
(No column name)    (No column name)    (No column name)    (No column name)
whatever            a                       1                       1000
who cares           b                       2                       2000
*/
```

Comment: thanks J0e3gan for replying, i don't want to cast the columns because it will not if i write some expressions in "Select", which i need to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use IF clause

```
IF(@groupBy = 'job')
Begin
  SELECT
        Name, job,min(jobCode), max(salary)s
  from TempTable
  Group by Name,@grouBy 
End

Else If(@groupBy = 'jobCode')
Begin
  SELECT
        Name, jobCode,min(job), max(salary)s
  from TempTable
  Group by Name,@grouBy 
End
```

Comment: True, but why repeat the bulk of the query?

Answer (score 0):

After juggling around the code, 
i found optional "Group By" working with columns having different datatypes.
in this method there is no need to CAST() your columns.

***1. Simple Example***

> Declare @groupBy varchar(50)
>   Set @groupBy = '**name**' -- or 'name' or 'jobCode'
>   Select 
>         min(Name), min(job), min(jobCode), max(salary)
>   from TempTable
>   Group by 
>       Case when @groupBy = 'name' then name End,
>       Case when @groupBy = 'job' then job End,
>       Case when @groupBy = 'jobCode' then jobCode End

***2. And For more aggregate functions in "Select clause" you can use like this.***

> Select 
>       Case 
>           when @grouBy = 'Name' then **min**(Name)
>           when @grouBy = 'job' then **count**(Name)
>           when @grouBy = 'jobCode' then **count**(Name)
>       End as Name
>       , max(Salary) as Salary 
>   From TempTable 
> Group by 
>       Case when @groupBy = 'name' then name End,
>       Case when @groupBy = 'job' then job End,
>       Case when @groupBy = 'jobCode' then jobCode End

Thank you **J0e3gan** and **mhasan** for your efforts.